# Django exceeds maximum Postgres connections

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, gunicorn, eventlet

I am experiencing a problem with a Django application that is exceeding the maximum number of simultaneous connections (100) to Postgres when running through `Gunicorn` with async `eventlet` workers. When the connection limit it reached the application starts returning `500`-errors until new connections can be established.

This is my database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'django',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
    }   
}
```

This is how Gunicorn is started:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-class eventlet --workers 5 myapp.wsgi:application
```

These are the installed packages:

- djano v1.7
- gunicorn v19.3
- eventlet v0.17
- psycopg2 v2.6

Is Django not able to reuse connections across HTTP requests when running with Gunicorn workers? Is some kind of 3rd party database connection pool my only option here?

**Update 15-03-23:** There appears to be a problem with `CONN_MAX_AGE` and async Gunicorn workers. Connections are indeed persistent but never reused in any sequential requests as noted in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/635100/django-conn-max-age-persists-connections-but-doesnt-reuse-them-with-postgresq). Setting `CONN_MAX_AGE` to `0` forces Django to close connections when the request ends, preventing unused persistent connections form laying around.

Answer (score 4):

Django does no database connection pooling. Have a look at PgBouncer. It is a lightweight connection pooled that is easy to setup and configure: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer

In short: Your django app connects to PgBouncer and it has a pool of connections to Postgres that it reuses, so the maximum connection limit is never exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

DB connection is stored in threads, Gunicorn eventlet class works based on greenlets (virtual threads), each creates a new separate db connection. Use Gthread or Sync class workers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654006/15907980