# Django: Postgres connection not closing

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery, webfaction

I have the problem that my django application accumulates postgres connections over time. It seems that about every 30min a new connection is established and the old connections don't close (see screen). 
As max connections is set to 100 after some time all connections are blocked.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

[image]

I discovered this after I integrated some `celery tasks`. So I am quite sure that it is related to celery.

So I tried to close the connection manually after every Task using `after_return` method:

```
from django.db import connection

class DBTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
        connection.close()

@task(name='example', base=DBTask)
def example_task(value):
    # do some stuff
```

But this also doesn't help. 
Maybe I am totally wrong and it isn't related to `celery` at all.

My database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'production', 
        'USER': 'production', 
        'HOST': 'some.host', 
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
    },
}
```

Installed packages:

- django 1.8.9
- pyscopg2 2.6.1
- celery 3.1.20
- django-celery 3.1.17

The app is deployed at [webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/) (maybe this helps)

I have also seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170542/django-exceeds-maximum-postgres-connections), but setting `CONN_MAX_AGE: 0` didn't help.

### Update:

Tried adding `connection.close()` at the end of each celery task, but the number of connection is still increasing.

### Update 2:

Tried adding `connection.close()` at the top of the celery file, but this didn't help either.

### Update 3:

Here is the code I am actually using in the celery tasks:

## celery_tasks.py

```
@task(name='push_notifications', base=DBTask)
def push_notifications_task(user_id):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
    PusherAPI().push_notifications(user)
    connection.close()
```

## models.py

```
class PusherAPI(object):

    def push_notifications(self, user):
        from .serializers import NotificationSerializer
        self.pusher.trigger(
            'user_%s' % user.slug,
            'notifications',
            NotificationSerializer(user).data
        )
```

## serializers.py

```
class NotificationSerializer(object):

    def __init__(self, user=None):
        if user is None:
            self.user = get_current_user()
        else:
            self.user = user

    @property
    def data(self):
        # get notifications from db
        notifications = self.user.notifications.unread()
        # create the notification dict
        ...
        return note_dict
```

The only db-queries are in `CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)` and `notifications = self.user.notifications.unread()`

Comment: Do your celery tasks use/create connections? If so, have you tried closing them within the celery tasks instead of later when the task is already done?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Do you think it makes any difference?

Comment: It could make a difference, as it might be different connections that would get closed in the tasks than the ones you're closing now outside the tasks. But I don't know celery enough to be sure of that.

Comment: I'll try it. I will let you know if it works

Comment: @das-g unfortunately this doesn't help

Comment: Try to close the connection at the begin of the file, not inside the class declaration.

Comment: @trinchet. Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: At the very top of your tasks file.

Comment: OK. I'll try that. But why do you think this would help? Isn't this only run once at startup?

Comment: Yeah, this run just one time, but that will close any missing open connection.

Comment: @trinchet, this didn't help. The connections are still increasing over time.

Comment: can you show where the `connection` object is created in your tasks - the code you show doesn't make sense - how is `connection` passed to `after_return` - is it a module-level variable?

Comment: @scytale, it is the connection from the `django.db` module. I import it with `from django.db import connection`.I edited my post.

Comment: and inside your celery tasks are you using the same `connection` object? could you show some sample code from your tasks that does the queries?

Comment: @scytale, I added all relevant code

Comment: that's way too much code - it's not all relevant - please reduce to just the bits that import/set up the db connection and some sample queries

Comment: in particular there's way too much serialization code that does not appear to be relevant at all

Comment: Sorry, reduced the code.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually old connections that are not closed and not new connections that pile up because some part of your application can't handle the load? Have you looked at the individual connections, e.g. with `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`?

Comment: Thanks @DanielHepper. With this I realized, that the issue is totally unrelated to the celery tasks. In fact it's not even the same databse causing the problems. Sorry for bothering you all! Could you post your suggestion as an answer, that I can reward you the bounty?

Comment: @ilse2005 Glad I could help! See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure it is actually old connections that are not closed and not new connections that pile up because some part of your application can't handle the load. Have a look at the individual connections, e.g. with `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`