# django with gunicorn persistent database connection not reused

Tags: django, gunicorn, gevent

Recently I have encounter an issue about django web site served by gunicorn and the worker_class is gevent.

The PostgreSQL database often complain too many connections, In django's settings.py I have set the database CONN_MAX_AGE to 6, so django will reuse the database connection within 6 seconds. But I found that django is not reusing them.

after some digging I found someone say that the async worker of gunicorn will cause this problem:

[Persistent database connections with async workers on Django >= 1.6 fails](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/996)

[Don't use Gunicorn to host your Django sites on Heroku](http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/)

But I guess that's the correct reason, but I don't know why.

Is there anyone can analysis this problem from the principle of async worker or the source code of gunicorn and explain this?

After reviewing the source code of django db module, I know that django save the database connection in ConnectionHandler()._connections which is a theading.local(), and will reuse it if it is not out of date. because of theading.local(), so it is thread separated.

But I think the async worker handle the request asynchronously and is within one single thread, so I don't know why async worker would cause this problem.

any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works:

- sync workers store the database connection (for each worker process) in a global the first time a connection is created. Subsequent requests to this process then use the same connection until it times out using `MAX_CONN_AGE` and then a new connection is created.
- gthread worker pre-creates threads and assigns each incoming request to a free thread for it to handle. The first time a database connection is required, it is created and stored in this thread's local. The same can now be reused when another request is assigned to this thread. The same `MAX_CONN_AGE` will take effect.
- The gevent worker does not pre-create threads. For each new request, a new thread (eventlet, to be precise) is spawned. Once the request is done, the eventlet dies. So, even though Django stores the connection in the local, it will never be reused. The connection will "leak" unless it is closed.

Now, could the gunicorn's gevent worker class have pre-created threads and used them instead? The answer is no because the gevent library does not have a concept of a thread pool. That's because creating a new greenlet takes hardly any resources or time, so it is quite pointless to have a concept of a pool.

There does exist a class called `gevent.Threadpool`, but note that is for creating *native* threads, not greenlets. There is also `gevent.pool.Pool` but that is not a pool like the `Threadpool`, it is just a `gevent.pool.Group` with a limit. `Group`s are used to group together eventlets that can be waited on to complete as a set.

So, when using the async gevent worker class, it is best to handle connections to the database via a separate database connection pool implementation such as `sqlalchemy.pool` after setting MAX_CONN_AGE to 0.